# Button looks different on Google Chrome (MAC)

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

For the above site, I started having an issue where a CSS button looks different on Google Chrome (MAC). This just started today.

CSS:

```
.cta-button {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffb14a 0px, #c76e08 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #a56317;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 18px arial;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #764711;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="cta-button" href="/free-consultation/">Start Your FREE Consultation</a>
```

What it looks like on Chrome (MAC):
[image: button on Chrome - MAC]

What it's supposed to look like - (FireFox - MAC)
[image: What it's supposed to look like]

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Hi, I cleared the cache. Still seeing the button looking weird.

Comment: But u might be right, as the button looks fine on Chrome Incognito (MAC).

Comment: The button looks fine to me on Chrome.

Comment: Go to the triple line options button, click "History", then go to "Clear browsing data...". From the drop-down select "the beginning of time", check all the boxes and push the "Clear browsing data" button.

Comment: The button looks fine. Chrome 47.0.2526.106 Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Browser stores external CSS pages in your cache based on their URLs.

Go to the triple line options button, click "History", then go to "Clear browsing data...". From the drop-down select "the beginning of time", check all the boxes and push the "Clear browsing data" button.